# ARkit delete infinite planes without restarting session?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

Does anyone know how to make ARkit delete infinite planes without restarting session? I'm currently trying to make my app detect one plane at a time and make it infinite. If a new plane is detected it should ideally delete the last plane and focus on the new one at whatever height the plane is at. Does anyone know how to do this without restarting the ARkit session? (Note that restarting the session causes all ARkit placed objects to lose their last position.)

Comment: Just to clarify, do you essentially want to track a single ARPlaneAnchor, and keep it updated?

Comment: Are you using ARKit in Unity?

Comment: How did you make inifinite plane once detected?